# How to set buttons on the edges of a div?

Tags: css, position

I have a weird problem, I am pretty bad with CSS therefor I come up with this exercise where I want to build a image slider, which is inside a div called slider-div with width of 1000px, from a array, 10 images are loaded into the div and only 5 are visible so the user have to scroll.

To learn more I added two buttons which should scroll 100px (left or right), 
I have a problem with those buttons, they stick to the parent slider-div / Background. I hoped they would always stay on the top and don't move. User can decide to scroll to the end or hit the buttons.
I am using display: flex; flex-direction: row; to get the images into a row.

How can I fix button to the visible edge of a div?

Only solution I worked out is:
position: fixed;
right: 33.6%;
but it is very unprofessional :( also bad when I changing the layout somewhere else.
Can you please look over and tell me where the mistake is what is missing?
Here is the link to codepen:

https://codepen.io/miomate/pen/pBQBya

Code:

```css
.div-1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

button{
  /* position: absolute; */
  top:35%;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}
.div-2-1{

}
.div-2-2{
right: 0;
}
```

The images aren't loaded but the result ist the same.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using the "bottom" property of css.

```
body {margin: 0 0 0 0;}
.div-1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.div-2-1{
  left:0;
}
.div-2-2{
 right: 0;
}
```